# API Gateway throws General SSLEngine problem

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, aws-api-gateway

I am getting below error when the API gateway endpoint is accessed

```
Wed Feb 13 05:20:49 UTC 2019 : Execution failed due to configuration error: General SSLEngine problem
Wed Feb 13 05:20:49 UTC 2019 : Method completed with status: 500
```

The API gateway is configured to point EC2 instance, I found client certificate was expired so I created a new one and mapped to API gateway. But still, I am receiving the error.

FYI: For SSL I have attached ACM certificate to API gateway.

Comment: Can you check whether the new certificate is issued by a supported certificate authority? (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-supported-certificate-authorities-for-http-endpoints.html). Regarding your statement "For SSL I have attached ACM certificate to API gateway.", could you explain more? For example, are you referring to the ACM certificate of the custom domain name of the API?

Comment: @DenisWeerasiri API Gateway can authenticate itself to the backend using a [client certificate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html) that API Gateway generates, itself.